# jQuery DataTables plugin: Sort German date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datatables

I use jQuery DataTables plugin and my problem is that my German date does not get ordered correctly. It has the following format: `dd.mm.YYYY HH:iih`

Here comes my code:

**JSFIDDLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/uxaLn1e3/3/

**HTML:**

```
    <table id="my-table">
   <thead>
      <th>Nr. </th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Name</th>
   </thead>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>27.08.2015 19:00h</td>
      <td>Carl</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>10.02.2016 14:00h</td>
      <td>Alan</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>07.12.2015 21:00h</td>
      <td>Bobby</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**JS (updated, with ajax):**

```
     $('#my-table').DataTable({
            "ajax": 'my_url',
            "columns": [
                {"data": "nr"},
                {"data": "date"},
                {"data": "name"}
            ],
                "autoWidth": false,
                "order": [],
                "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
                   var dateFull = aData.date;
                   var dateFullItems = dateFull.split(' ');
                   var dateDatum = dateFullItems[0];
                   var dateDatumItems = dateDatum.split('.');
                  var dateTime = dateFullItems[1];
                  var dateFormat = dateDatumItems[2] + '-' + dateDatumItems[1] + '-' + dateDatumItems[0] + 'T' + dateTime + ':00Z'; 

                  $(nRow).find('td:nth-of-type(2)').attr('data-sort', dateFormat);
            },
            });
```

What adjustments do I need to do in my JS for the sorting of date to work?

Comment: You can try this [Ultimate date/time sorting plug-in](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18)

Comment: I already tried. I put `$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD.MM.YYY HH:mm' )` just before my `$('#my-table').DataTable(...)` declaration. I get the following console error message:  `$.fn.dataTable.moment is not a function`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a `data-sort` attribute to the `td` having the date stored in a Standard Format (I have used ISO Format here i.e. `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:ii:ssZ` ):

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td data-sort="2015-08-27T19:00:00Z">27.08.2015 19:00h</td>
  <td>Carl</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-sort="2016-02-10T14:00:00Z">10.02.2016 14:00h</td>
  <td>Alan</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td data-sort="2015-12-07T21:00:00Z">07.12.2015 21:00h</td>
  <td>Bobby</td>
</tr>
```

Now `datatables` will consider this `data-sort` value instead of the html of `td` to sort the columns.

[**Live Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/uxaLn1e3/4/)

Even if you are creating the table dynamically you can achieve this in two ways:

A. Add a `data-sort` attribute while generating the html.

B. Add a `data-sort` after the datatable is created using jQuery and then reinit the datatable.

Comment: You might even want to go one step further and use either bare timestamp values, which have no time-zone, or use UTC time and ISO-8601 formatting for sortability.

Comment: Just noticed now you're using Zulu time which is one thing I was recommending.

Comment: Nice feature. See also this [official example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)

Comment: @void: Thank you. I actually do use ajax to load my data. `"ajax": '{{ url('my_url', { 'idUser' : ''}) }}' + id,
            "columns": [
                {"data": "nr"},
                {"data": "date"},
                {"data": "name"}
            ]`  I don't understand how to add the data-sort attribute with the date in this context. Could you please explain?

Comment: I just updated my post. How can the data-sort solution get integrated into the updated code?

Comment: @void I tried it with fnCreatedRow and the data-sort attribute gets inserted correctly. But still, sorting fails. Please see my updated post.

Comment: Can you please update the fiddle with the new JS code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must using a datetime format plugin for your gender data script, or a plugin for sortting your formatted datetime ([Ultimate date / time sorting plug-in](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18) is my recommend)

Sample on your case: jsfiddle.net/x92amfe4/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the dates by making JavaScript date objects from the strings. 
You then only need to split up the german date ("dd.mm.yy") and make a new date:

```
      new Date(date.split('.')[2], date.split('.')[1]-1, date.split('.')[0])
```

For sorting german dates:

```
dates.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(b.split('.')[2], b.split('.')[1]-1, b.split('.')[0]) - new Date(a.split('.')[2], a.split('.')[1]-1, a.split('.')[0]) 
});
```

---

Note:
You can use **any date format** to create a JavaScript date object.

```
new Date(year, month(0-11) [, day [, hour [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);
```